# Running Web Application which has higher .NET Framework version compare to .NET Framework version of server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-framework-version

I have an MVC 5 Application which is based on .NET Framework  4.5 
I want to know, is it possible to run the application on a server (Windows Server 2008 R2) which is based on .NET Framework  4?

Comment: Have you tried running it anyway?

Comment: Not yet. I want to know first.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need .net 4.5 installed on the server to run a .net 4.5 application.